# Addition table for a 4 elements field

Tags: field-theory

Why is this addition table good,
\begin{matrix}
\boldsymbol{\textbf{}+} & \mathbf{0} & \boldsymbol{\textbf{}1} & \textbf{a} &\textbf{ b}\\ 
\boldsymbol{\textbf{}0} & 0 & 1 & a & b\\ 
\boldsymbol{\textbf{}1} & 1 & 0 & b & a\\ 
\boldsymbol{\textbf{} a} & a & b & 0 & 1\\ 
\boldsymbol{\textbf{} b} &b & a & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}

and this one isn't, what makes it not work?
\begin{matrix}
\boldsymbol{\textbf{}+} & \mathbf{0} & \boldsymbol{\textbf{}1} & \textbf{a} &\textbf{ b}\\ 
\boldsymbol{\textbf{}0} & 0 & 1 & a & b\\ 
\boldsymbol{\textbf{}1} & 1 & a & b & 0\\ 
\boldsymbol{\textbf{} a} & a & b & 0 & 1\\ 
\boldsymbol{\textbf{} b} &b & 0 & 1 & a
\end{matrix}

It's clear that $0$ and $a$ changes places in the second table but I can't find an example that refutes any of the addition axioms.

Comment: If you literally relabel: $0 \rightarrow a$ and $a \rightarrow 0$ then why would this addition table be less valid (other than the fact that it is a bit unintuitive because the identity element is labeled $a$ instead of $0$)?

Comment: The change is true only inside the table, not in the title of each row\column. Any yet the relabel is not 100% because the changes are only in the 2nd and 4th rows\columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second table is perfectly fine. It is actually $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

To see that there is no field with additive group $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ consider the following:
$$aa =(1+1)(1+1) = 1\cdot 1+1\cdot 1+1\cdot 1+1\cdot 1=0.$$

Comment: So a 4 elements field have more than one addition table? can I say that?

Comment: While $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is a perfectly fine abelian group, it is not the addition group of any field.

Comment: I think you're over-killing it. I was supposed to build an addition table of a 4 elements field, I came up with the second table but I was told that the right answer is the first table. I want to know why is my table bad, cause I can't find any axiom that it is not enduring.

Answer (score 2):

If you have only one operation, it is difficult to speak about field. But, it is well-known that:

1) there exists exactly two groups (up to isomorphism) with 4 elements: one is ${\mathbb Z}/2{\mathbb Z}\times{\mathbb Z}/2{\mathbb Z}$ (the first table) and the other one is ${\mathbb Z}/4{\mathbb Z}$ (the second table)

2) there exists exaclty one field (up to isomorphism) with 4 elements, and it is isomorphic to ${\mathbb Z}/2{\mathbb Z}\times{\mathbb Z}/2{\mathbb Z}$

Comment: Actually I have two operations but the multiplication table was too easy to think of.

Comment: Is ${\mathbb Z}/2{\mathbb Z}\times{\mathbb Z}/2{\mathbb Z}$ is isomorphic to Klein $4$-group?

Comment: @J.G: how do you define the Klein $4$-group? One possible definition is that *it is* ${\mathbb Z}/2{\mathbb Z}\times{\mathbb Z}/2{\mathbb Z}$.